# Beginning a letter in latin--what were common conventions

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, contemporary-latin, conversational

In the USA, it is customary to begin a letter with "Dear" and the name of the recipient. E.g., "Dear Dr. Smith" or "Dear Alex".

Was there a similar convention for the opening of a letter written in Latin in various eras? E.g., Classical Latin, Medieval Latin, Contemporary Latin, etc. What were those conventions, and which era(s) did those conventions belong to? I am guessing it changed over time.

Comment: Hi Josh and welcome. The main thrust of your question has been answered before, so I'm closing this and linking to those questions. Also, the site is set up in a way to basically function as a Q&A with one main question per topic. I think you have an interesting question with focusing on the change, so if you'd like, after reading the other threads, you can edit it to focus only on that aspect, which I do not believe has been asked and answered before. (Or you can edit to focus on something else that isn't fully covered by the linked questions, whichever you like.)

Comment: Let me know if this makes sense and if you have any questions about this or how our works (just saw that you're not new to SE, just Latin!). Feel free to ping me with "@cmw" to get my attention or join us in the chatroom CONLOQVIVM.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the links! I did try and search but didn't find these questions, thank you for providing the links.